# Validation error with Node on NestJs when trying to save data to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

[image]

I recieved this error when trying to save to MongoDB database using NestJs framework.

Below is my function in service file.

```
async insertProduct(title: string, desc: string, price: number) {
    //const prodId = Math.random().toString();
    const newProduct = new this.productModel({
      title: title,
      description: desc,
      price: price,
    });
    const result = await newProduct.save(); //the save method here is provided by moongose and the save method will return promise
    console.log(result);
    //return result.id as string;
    return 'test';
  }
```

Below is my model

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
});

export interface Product {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Below is product module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Product', schema: ProductSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [ProductsService],
})
```

I am trying to send post request from postman and get data in console and also update in MongoDatabase. It is not working. I was following a video from Academind in Youtube while practising this project. Although it worked for them it's not working for me.

Any help will be gladly appreciated. Thank You everyone!